# I don´t get any bitmap using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, video, bitmap, ffmpeg, frame

I´m developing an app to extract the frames of a video, but I can´t use MediaMetadataRetriever because it fails a lot of times. So I found a external library called FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever wrote by William Seemann to extract the frames. But I don´t get any bitmap using the method FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(long time).

This is the code I´m trying:

```
    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mediaData = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaData.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/video.mp4");

    frame = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frame);
    frame.setImageBitmap(mediaData.getFrameAtTime());
```

Instead, I can get metadata from the video and I can extract frames using MedaMetadataRetriever, so I think the video is right.

I don´t know why I´m not able to extract the frames. If the library works well for me I will be very pleased.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the code that was causing null frames to be returned, I just fixed the issue. Please perform a fresh checkout of the code and try again.

Comment: Okey!! thanks! It works nice but I have a doubt: What do I have to put in the method getFrameAtTime?? seconds, miliseconds or microseconds?? It seems that there´s a method getFrameAtTime(long timeUs, int option). But it isn´t exists really. I need to extract frames of a video with some precission... Thanks!!